# AngularでのTabulatorのテストコードの書き方が分からない

Tags: angular, jasmine

AngularでTabulatorを使用しています。
headerClickにて独自の処理を入れているのですが、そこのテストコードの書き方がわかりません。
もしわかる方いらっしゃいましたら教えていただきたいです。

```
column: any[] = [
    {title:"Name",
     field:"name",
     width:150,
     headerClick: (e:any, column:any) => {
       // ここ
     }
    },
  ];

private drawTable(): any {
    var tabulator = new Tabulator(this.tab, {
      data: this.tableData,
      reactiveData:true,
      columns: this.column,
      layout: 'fitData',
    });
    
    document.getElementById('my-tabular-table').appendChild(this.tab);

    return tabulator
  }
```